# jsonp callback error

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, cross-domain, jsonp, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using firefox addon builder. Running this code errors with "callback is not defined"

```
function callback(data) {
   window.alert(data.status);
}

$.ajax({
   url: "http://apps.compete.com/sites/google.com/trended/rank/?apikey=210e634a0b3af972daa908a447c735c1&start_date=201112&end_date=201112&jsonp=?",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   jsonp: "jsonp",
   jsonpCallback: "callback"
});
```

This is the api documentation: https://www.compete.com/developer/documentation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are running this from a content script. You have to consider that content scripts don't really run in the same context as the web page's scripts - the web page cannot see functions defined by content scripts and vice versa ([detailed description of this mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper)). JSONP works by inserting a `<script>` tag into the web page. This script will run in the context of the web page - and it won't see the callback function you defined in the content script.

To define the `callback` function in the window context you do:

```
unsafeWindow.callback = function(data)
{
  window.alert(data.status);
};
```

However, you should take the [warnings about `unsafeWindow` in the documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/dev-guide/addon-development/content-scripts/access.html) seriously and avoid it if possible. Use the [`request` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/addon-kit/docs/request.html) in your extension to load the data:

```
require("request").Request({
  url: "http://apps.compete.com/sites/google.com/trended/rank/?apikey=210e634a0b3af972daa908a447c735c1&start_date=201112&end_date=201112",
  onComplete: function(response)
  {
    console.log(response.json);
  }
});
```

You can then send `response.json` to your content script via [usual messaging](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/dev-guide/addon-development/content-scripts/using-postmessage.html).

Comment: thanks Wladimir : as usual your answer solved the jsonp issue for me. I was making $.ajax jsonp calls from content script and the callback was not getting fired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://apps.compete.com/sites/google.com/trended/rank/?apikey=210e634a0b3af972daa908a447c735c1&start_date=201112&end_date=201112&jsonp=?",
     dataType: "jsonp",
     success: function(data) {
         window.alert(data.status);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not append `jsonp=?` to your url, this is done by the ajax function.

Use only:

```
url: "http://apps.compete.com/sites/google.com/trended/rank/?apikey=<your-api-key>&start_date=201112&end_date=201112",
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in response to Marcelo Diniz, and anyone trying to get the compete API working:
You need `&jsonp=?` appended to your url or else your ajax request will always fail.

I struggled with this for a while because the docs from compete were vague.