# Making Ajax Request From PageMod ContentScriptFile

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building this in beta builder and I am really lost as to how to get an ajax call to happen inside my contentScriptFile. I want to pull an ajax request to dynamically pull databack into script so I can alter page contents. I've been searching and searching and apparently for the wrong terms. Help is appreciated! Thanks

main.js

Code:

```
exports.main = function() {};
var data = require("self").data;
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "http://www.mozilla.org/*",
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    contentScriptFile: [
        data.url('jquery.1.7.1.js'),
        data.url('common.js'),
        data.url("mozilla.top.js")
    ]
})
```

mozilla.top.js

Code:

```
var qs = parseQS();
var foo= qs['string'];
var Request = require('request').Request;

Request({
  url: "http://www.myremotepage.org?q="+foo,
  onComplete: function (response) {
    alert(response);
  }
}).get();
alert('test');
```

old code to shed light on end goal - http request returns nothing, even though it works in browser. Assumed it was permissions issue with 3rd party ajax tools and started above using add-on request tool.

Code:

```
/*
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.myremotepage.org?q='+foo,
    data: {q:strSearchQuery},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var div = $("<div style='background-color: #ececec;'><h2 style='text-align: right; font-size: 11px; color: #666;'>Test</h2><ul id='ptcid'></ul></div>");
        alert(data.length);
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
        {
            alert('test');
            div.find('ul').append('<li></li>');
            div.find('ul li:last').append('<h3>' + data[i].header+ '</h3>');
            div.find('ul li:last').append('<div>'+data[i].body+'</div>');
            div.find('ul li:last').append('<div>' + data[i].footer + '</div>');
        }
        div.insertBefore('#header');
    }
});
*/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsonp callback error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961091/jsonp-callback-error). At the very least, my answer there applies to your question as well.

Comment: So the request would be in the main portion - main.js and the callback would be in mozilla.top.js?  How does the request know to wait until the pagemod is ready?  Also docs say to not use unsafe window - so there has to be a better more correct way.

Answer (score 2):

One immediate problem you have is that mozilla.top.js is added as a content script, and tries to use the Request module. You cannot use SDK modules such as request in a content script, you need to instead make the request in main.js and then deliver the request data into your content script by using worker.port.emit(). The docs go into some detail about content script communications:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/dev-guide/addon-development/content-scripts/using-port.html

A sample implementation would look like:

```
var pm = require("page-mod").PageMod({
    include: [page_url],
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery.min.js'), data.url('panel.js')],
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        Request({
            url: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1212936/test.json",
            onComplete: function (response) {
                var parsed = JSON.parse(response.text);
                worker.port.emit('got-request', parsed);
            }
        }).get();
    }
});
```

In your content script: you would attach a listener to the 'got-request' event:

```
self.port.on('got-request', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#data').html(pp(data));
});
```

Here's a working example on builder that uses this code - it's very very simple but hopefully will help:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1034982/latest/